# Kendo - 2 data sources on the same chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I have 2 data sources on 2 different charts and I would like to combine them to be on the same chart. They both have the same X-axis. How can I do it?

```
var sharedDataSourceA = ...
var sharedDataSourceB = ...

$("#chart1").kendoChart({
                    dataSource: ???
                    ...
```

Comment: Combine them in code first then feed the combined datasource to the chart. If you need help combining them, show us what the individual datasources they look like.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you first combine the two dataSources together, and in your data, have a "group" attribute so that the chart can distinguish between the two.

Kendo have a demonstration of the kendoChart groupedData here: [KendoChart Grouped Data](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/grouped-data)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate both datasources by extracting json arrays with [toJSON](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/data/observableobject#methods-toJSON) method then concatenate them with [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) method. Finally construct new datasource object with the result array

see [Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eMUqO)

```
var dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe" },
    { name: "John Doe" }
  ]
});
var dataSource2 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe2" },
    { name: "John Doe2" }
  ]
});
dataSource1.fetch();
dataSource2.fetch();
var array1 = dataSource1.data().toJSON();
var array2 = dataSource2.data().toJSON(); 

var newData = array1.concat(array2);
var dataSource3 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: newData
});
```

Comment: @mohacs done with including the essential parts of the answer